# How does one call cmdline arguments such as `prog -vvv` or `prog -dd`?

Tags: command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

Is there an established name for a program's command line argument whose value is determined by the number of repetitive occurrences of the parameter's name or short-handle (as opposed to passing a keyword-value pair)?

E.g `prog -vvv` instead of `prog -v 3` for the degree of verbosity or some compiler's debug mode via `compiler -dd` instead of `compiler -d 2`.

I recently came across this idiom and I find it very neat. Would like to know this puppy's name. Thanks!